# Move the Canary Islands and zoom in on the peninsula on a ggplot map with r and sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have tried to move the geometries of the Canary Islands towards the peninsula so that the map of Spain is seen on a larger scale to represent information by provinces.

I have started from the shapefile of this ESRI location

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=83d81d9336c745fd839465beab885ab7

The code used is this, you need `ggplot2` and `sf`

```
geoprovincias <- st_read("ruta/Provincias_ETRS89_30N.shp")

geopenínsula <- geoprovincias[!geoprovincias$CCAA=="Canarias",]
geocanarias <- geoprovincias[geoprovincias$CCAA=="Canarias",]

crs <- st_crs(geopenínsula)

geocanariasco <- geocanarias %>% 
 st_transform(crs) %>%
 st_geometry()
geocanariasco <- geocanariasco + c(5, 7)

geocanarias <- geocanarias %>% 
 st_set_geometry(geocanariasco) %>%
 st_set_crs(crs)

geoprovincias <- rbind(geopenínsula, geocanarias)

mprovincias <- geoprovincias %>% 
 ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
   fill="white",
   color="#1D1D1D",
   size=0.5
  ) +
 theme_void()
mprovincias
```

Comment: I believe you may find the {mapSpain} package helpful; especially https://ropenspain.github.io/mapSpain/reference/esp_get_can_box.html

Comment: Thanks. It is very useful. However, I wish I could resolve the question.

Comment: One approach is to make insets or compose a layout with two plots using `cowplot` or `patchwork`. For example see: https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf-3.html

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve from a different source,

http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/index.jsp

Following the links: Reference geographic information - Municipal, provincial and autonomous limits - Download: lineas_limite.zip.

The path in the uncompressed folder: SIGLIM_Publico_INSPIRE:

- SHP_ETRS89 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp
- SHP_WGS84 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84.shp

The code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rmapshaper)

geopropenínsula <- st_read("ruta/recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp")
geoprocanarias <- st_read("ruta/recintos_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84.shp")

crs <- st_crs(geopropenínsula) #CRS Península, Baleares, Ceuta y Melilla

geoprocanariasco <- geoprocanarias %>% 
 st_transform(crs) %>% #We transform the geometries of the Canary Islands
 st_geometry() #We extract the geometries.
geoprocanariasco <- geoprocanariasco + c(5, 7) #Move Canarias

geoprocanarias <- geoprocanarias %>% 
 st_set_geometry(geoprocanariasco) %>%  #We change the geometries of the Canary Islands.
 st_set_crs(crs) # We will specify the CRS of the Península for the Islas Canarias again.

geoprovincias <- rbind(geopropenínsula, geoprocanarias) #Join
geoprovincias$CódigoProvincia <- substring(geoprovincias$NATCODE, 5, 6)

# We eliminate the territory not associated with any province.
geoprovincias <- geoprovincias[!geoprovincias$CódigoProvincia=="54",]

# We simplify the provincial boundaries and smooth the lines.
geosprovincias <- ms_simplify(geoprovincias, keep = 0.00050, weighting = 6)

mapapro <- geosprovincias %>%
 ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using some coordinate limits and plot them separately on two plots then to combine them into one. Still need some work to make it more elegant.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(gridExtra)

# my location of the shape file
geoprovincias <- st_read("/S/sinh/Documents/Professional/SO/data/Provincias_ETRS89_30N/Provincias_ETRS89_30N.shp")

geopenínsula <- geoprovincias[!geoprovincias$CCAA=="Canarias",]
geocanarias <- geoprovincias[geoprovincias$CCAA=="Canarias",]

crs <- st_crs(geopenínsula)

geocanariasco <- geocanarias %>% 
  st_transform(crs) %>%
  st_geometry()
geocanariasco <- geocanariasco + c(5, 7)

geocanarias <- geocanarias %>% 
  st_set_geometry(geocanariasco) %>%
  st_set_crs(crs)

geoprovincias <- rbind(geopenínsula, geocanarias)

# This part is for calculate the limit for sf cordinate #####
{
  # all countries at scale 10m
  ctrys <- ne_countries(scale = 10, type = "countries", returnclass = "sf")
  
  crsLONGLAT <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
  crsLAEA <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=12 +lon_0=5 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
  
  bb <- st_sfc(
    st_polygon(list(cbind(
      c(-10, 5, 5, -10, -10), # x-coordinates (longitudes) of points A,B,C,D
      c(35, 35, 45, 45, 35)     # y-coordinates (latitudes) of points A,B,C,D
    ))),
    crs = crsLONGLAT)
  
  # now in in LAEA projection
  laeabb <- st_transform(bb, crs = crsLAEA)
  
  # the extent of the bounding box in the new projection
  b <- st_bbox(laeabb)
  big_part <- b
}

# the big part plot
mprovincias_1 <- geoprovincias %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    fill="white",
    color="#1D1D1D",
    size=0.5
  ) + coord_sf(crs = crsLAEA, xlim = c(big_part["xmin"], big_part["xmax"]),
               ylim = c(big_part["ymin"], big_part["ymax"])) +
  theme_void()

# This part is for calculate the coordlimit for the small island
{
  bb <- st_sfc(
    st_polygon(list(cbind(
      c(-19, -13, -13, -19, -19), # x-coordinates (longitudes) of points A,B,C,D
      c(27, 27, 30, 30, 27)     # y-coordinates (latitudes) of points A,B,C,D
    ))),
    crs = crsLONGLAT)
  
  # now in in LAEA projection
  laeabb <- st_transform(bb, crs = crsLAEA)
  
  # the extent of the bounding box in the new projection
  b <- st_bbox(laeabb)
  small_island <- b
  }

# the island plot
mprovincias_2 <- geoprovincias %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    fill="white",
    color="#1D1D1D",
    size=0.5
  ) + coord_sf(crs = crsLAEA, xlim = c(small_island["xmin"], small_island["xmax"]),
               ylim = c(small_island["ymin"], small_island["ymax"])) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1, fill = NA))


# combine the two in one a bit clumsy
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(mprovincias_1, mprovincias_2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                         heights = c(4, 1)))
```

[image: Map with zoom]